# Determine if sessions are enabled client-side

Tags: php, session, status

How can I determine, if client browser supports sessions?

I'm working on a anti-flood script - I want to limit the operations on the script to 5 seconds for each operation, and I want to store the unix time using the client sessions, but first I'd have to check if they're enabled. Is that possible to do that?

Comment: Client Sessions? Are you referring to a JS Database?

Comment: and if not, they can still flood you. odd approach. what's being "flooded" ?

Comment: Is it anti-flood against good users (unintentional behaviour) or bad users (intentional behaviour)?

Comment: bad users , I just want myself from being flooded by typical bad user hitting F5 and flooding my database with the select query in the script.

Comment: insert query? add unique indexes. Select, should not be an issue. Follow up to S.O comments should be faster than half an hour, things move fast around here.

Comment: Its a select query I'm just selecting two fields for one record from my database (MySQL) - wont it hurt the server?

Comment: well what's the server designed to do? serve web pages? most come from a db, your trying to fix a non existent problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to limit the script from running more than once every 5 seconds per client.

Http is a stateless protocol, and PHP relies on a cookie value (or parameter value) to initialize the session on the server side. Knowing this, using sessions alone is not enough to stop users from flooding your script more than once every 5 seconds. The user client could simple not send the cookie or session ID parameter in the request, and you would have to treat it like a new session.

You will have to use other methods of identifying user sessions. Using the requesting IP address is a good start, but may not work very well for you (especially since many users can have the same public facing IP).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another approach. At every pageload, create a new cookie (if it doesn't already exist). When you are using the script you simply check if the cookie exists, if it does and the value is ok, then everything is fine. Otherwise you disable the script from running.

Comment: How would this protect from flood?